# Why OffsetTop and offsetLeft not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my canvas and when I click I get X and Y, e.g. x=10 y=10, and when I use scrollbar drop and click in the same position I will get x= not 10 and y=not 10. Why?

```
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        topCanvas = canvas.offsetTop;
        leftCanvas = canvas.offsetLeft;
    function click(e)
    {
    console.log("x="+(e.clientX-leftCanvas));
    console.log("y="+(e.clientY-topCanvas));
    }
    </script>
```

Why scrollbar not helping..

Answer (score 0):

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let topCanvas = canvas.offsetTop;
let leftCanvas = canvas.offsetLeft;
canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('not considering scroll position');
  console.log("  x=" + (e.clientX - leftCanvas));
  console.log("  y=" + (e.clientY - topCanvas));
  console.log('considering scroll position');
  console.log("  x=" + e.layerX);
  console.log("  y=" + e.layerY);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I check if a scrollbar has been used?

Comment: you could compare the 2 coordinates

Comment: why is undefined?